# Vertical align a 1 or 2 line link in a div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have little circles with a text in it (continents).
They could be only 1 word 'Europe', or 2 words like 'North America'.

I want to center them vertically. I mean I could give them different classes, but this goes through a CMS and I was hoping to find a solution with CSS or JS.

```
<div class="round"><a href="#">Europe</a></div>

<div class="round"><a href='#'>North America</a></div>
```

I created a little jsfiddle to show you the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmtqzvy6/

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: in your fiddle, is there a reason you are doing all that craziness to make a circle, rather than just equal width and height with 100% border radius? it is a lot easier to center if it is that way instead.

Comment: haha no that 'craziness' is not necessary. I just wanted to show you guys that I have that circle and i need to center either a 1 or 2 line link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://jsfiddle.net/6mo13fj8/:

```
.round {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.round a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use position absolute to center your link inside the circle:

```
.round {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position:relative;
}
.round a {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fmtqzvy6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ph89j3a/
This should work:

```
.round a {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display:block;
}
```

More info how to vertically align with css: http://codepen.io/sebastianekstrom/pen/kzEhe